# Nodeschool learnyounode Filter LS exercise: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I have not used .`forEach()` method in my solution. Here is my solution:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

fs.readdir(process.argv[2], function (err, list) {

    if(err)
        return console.log(err);

    for(var i=0;list[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if('.'+process.argv[3]===path.extname(list[i].toString()))
            console.log(list[i]);       

    }

});
```

I am getting the following error:

```
if('.'+process.argv[3]===path.extname(list[i].toString()))
                                                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at /home/dhairyakhale/Desktop/NodeTutorials/program.js:11:49
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)
```

If I don't use `.toString()`, it shows me the error that 'Path must be a string'. What is the reason behind not accepting my solution?

Comment: Seems like `list[i]` doesn't exist. Can you move the console.log above the if statement and see what the value of `list[i]` is when it throws the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the list being returned is an array of filename strings. The exit condition for your for loop should be as follow:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
}
```

That way you are assured to only loop through the existing items. I believe that you are going outside the bounds of the array, which is the reason for your undefined error.

You also don't need to do cast toString() inside the for loop. The array elements are already strings.

Arrays provide a built in filter method, it could be useful in this exercise.

Using `forEach` also helps and makes things more readable, although it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: You are right. This solution is working. Thank you so much!

On a side note, do arrays not end with an escape character, like `'\0'`?

Comment: Not to the best of my knowledge for the Javascript language. Usually in Javascript you'll know you are outside the bounds of the array if you have undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In some index `list[i]` is arriving as undefined (null).
make sure you are doing the correct iteration

Comment: Yes. Using `'\0'` as the condition was making the array go out of bounds.